# Sum a column's positive values only if multiple columns contain a specific text

Tags: excel, sumproduct

I have a column P with positive and negative values but I only want to add up the positive values if columns V:Z contain a specific text. I've got it to work with checking 1 column:

**=SUMPRODUCT(P2:P29, (V2:V29=A43)*(P2:P29>0))**

But if I change the range from V2:Z29, I get a #VALUE error. Any help would be great appreciated.

Comment: Are we talking OR(can be in any of the columns) or AND(Has to be in all the columns)?

Comment: @ScottCraner can be in any of the columns. To provide an example, if cells V3, W4, and X5 contain the word "dog" and their values in P3, P4, P5 are 5, 6, and -7 accordingly, I only want to add cells P3 and P4.

Comment: @kaykayok What is excel version? We can achieve your desired result with MMULT & FILTER function if you have Excel365.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
SUMPRODUCT(P2:P29, SIGN((V2:V29=A43)+(W2:W29=A43)+(X2:X29=A43)+(Y2:Y29=A43)+(Z2:Z29=A43))*(P2:P29>0))
```

The `+` acts like `OR` much like `*` acts like `AND`.  `SIGN` is there to account for duplicates in the columns.